# Is It possible to write drivers for a java card

Tags: java, drivers, javacard

I am doing a project on java cards and I have searched the internet and I didn't find anything.
I was wondering if it was possible to write drivers for a java sim card, load it into the sim card so it can work for your own personal built API to perform some kind of function. I know the java card memory size is limited but the driver size to is very small and the function does not require a lot of memory.

You see the JVM runs like an OS on the java SIM CARD in which the JCRE runs on top to handle the applets written in a .cap format but you see the JVM or JCRE would have to communicate with the Java SIM CARD using drivers which I presume would be stored in the ROM(Am not totally sure of this but its what I think) now my question is:

(1) what is the native language the drivers are written in and can I write one similar to it so that my driver runs with the JCRE

(2) The sole purpose of my driver is to create a similar frame work to that of JavaFx but runs on the java card i.e. once the Java Card is in and the phone is turned on, powering the card it runs an applet that create an interface on screen of the mobile device.  I know the constraints of RAM size and EEPROM size of the Card but I also thought of using the phones CPU/GPU through the Card and making the codes and processing power as small/light as possible.(I know it sounds kind of dumb)

So is it possible or am I just day dreaming?

Comment: In general you can create libraries for Java Card. Drivers normally are used to drive hardware devices. Can you explain a bit more on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @owlstead I have edited my question and what am trying to achieve. Thnaks

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't possible. The JavaCard system (JVM, JCRE and the underlying OS which deals with the hardware) is one package provided by the vendor. It's not extensible in any way.
The only thing you have to work with are the JavaCard APIs and any extra non-standard APIs provided by the JavaCard vendor.

Comment: So your saying I cannot add features to the JCRE or JCVM? The implementation of the JCVM is from the JVM though lots of features or functionalities have been stripped off due to the size of the cards. now I want to write codes to add just a feature and you say it impossible?

Comment: Indeed, there isn't anything like JNI that gives access to the underlying hardware or native OS libraries - again unless a proprietary API has been defined by a vendor.